# ILScene does not update in WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, ilnumerics, windowsformshost

I am attempting to use an ILLinePlot to plot live data in a WPF app using WindowsFormsHost. I have made a start based on these two SO questions:
[ILScene in WindowsFormsHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314146/ilscene-in-windowsformshost) & [ILNumeric continuous rendering plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173259/ilnumeric-continuous-rendering-plots).

My code is:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Pulse_Generator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="ILView_OnLoaded">
    <Grid Name="grid1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <forms:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WindowsFormsHost" Margin="5" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ILPanel ilPanel;

    private void IlPanelOnLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        using (ILScope.Enter())
        {
            // generate some dummy data
            int N = 50000;
            ILArray<float> x = ILMath.vec<float>(0, N-1);
            ILArray<float> y = ILMath.tosingle(ILMath.rand(N));
            ILArray<float> A = ILMath.zeros<float>(2, N);
            A["0;:"] = x;
            A["1;:"] = y;

            ilPanel.Scene.Add(new ILPlotCube(){
                new ILLinePlot(A)
            });

            ilPanel.BeginRenderFrame += (o, args) =>
            {
                using (ILScope.Enter())
                {
                    var linePlot = ilPanel.Scene.First<ILLinePlot>();
                    var posBuffer = linePlot.Line.Positions;
                    ILArray<float> data = posBuffer.Storage;
                    // update the plot with some new dummy data
                    data["1;:"] = ILMath.tosingle(ILMath.randn(1, posBuffer.DataCount));
                    linePlot.Line.Positions.Update(data);
                    ilPanel.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>().Reset();
                    linePlot.Configure();
                }
            };
            // start running
            ilPanel.Clock.TimeMilliseconds = 15;
            ilPanel.Clock.Running = true;
        }
    }

    private void ILView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ilPanel = new ILPanel();
        ilPanel.Load += IlPanelOnLoad;
        WindowsFormsHost.Child = ilPanel;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the plot only updates (and BeginRenderFrame only appears to be triggered) when there is mouse interaction on the plot (click/drag/scroll) or the window is resized.

Presumably this is because the clock is not running properly inside the WindowsFormsHost?

Answer (score 0):

Without having too much experience with wpf I think you are right: the clock in ILNumerics plot panel uses Application.Idle which is not raised in WPF.

I found a similar post in SO which describes a workaround: [Application.Idle event not firing in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344398/application-idle-event-not-firing-in-wpf-application)

According to that post, you could try

```
ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += (sender, e) => System.Windows.Forms.Application.RaiseIdle(e);
```